# fabric-rails: Uncaught ReferenceError: fabric is not defined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I've got to be missing the most basic thing. 
I'm trying to use fabric.js in my rails 4 app. The installation for fabric-rails gem is as easy as could be.

I have added `gem "fabric-rails"` to my gemfile. I have run bundle install, no errors. I have added `//= require fabric` to my application.js file.

Here's a super basic example I'm trying from the fabric.js tutorial:

```html
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>


<script>
  // create a wrapper around native canvas element (with id="c")
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

  // create a rectangle object
  var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    fill: 'red',
    width: 20,
    height: 20
  });

  // "add" rectangle onto canvas
  canvas.add(rect);
</script>
```

And yet,  I get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: fabric is not defined" on line 7: `var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');` Which is presumably means that somehow, it doesn't recognize fabric.js

It's got to be something obvious I'm missing?

UPDATE: I never did figure it out, I just added fabric.js to my assets and loaded it manually. I'd still rather use a gem to make sure it stays updated in the future, but *shrug*